# How would I go about creating a Facebook Fan Page tab that contains a Poll?

Tags: facebook

I'm not sure why but creating any kind of integration beyond the use of social widgets and buttons on external sites always confuses me.

What I need to do is create a tab on a particular Fan Page. This tab needs to:

1. Contain an interface for casting a vote in a Poll.
2. Handle multiple Polls. Only one will be featured in the tab at a time, but there should be an interface for navigating to previous polls.
3. All polling data needs to be stored on my servers - 3rd party Polling solutions (facebook apps, or embedable services) are not an option unless the data storage location is configurable.

All those requirements are pretty easy to address. Im just confused about how to integrate with FB.

- Do i need full FB App for this, or is there another way? This will only be accessible via the Fan Page tab, so I don't necessarily need an App at apps.facebook.com.
- If it is an app... is there a way to hide the app page, and the standalone app canvas from everyone except Fan Page admins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Static FBML](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=4949752878&b) app that Facebook provides.  You can implement it on any Facebook fan page, change the tab title, and specify the content in HTML/FBML (with some limitations, I believe IFRAMES, password inputs, and some other random things are not allowed, but don't take my word on these until you test them).  Hopefully this at least gives you a little head start.

Answer (score 1):

FBML will be discountinue very soon. You might need to find an alternative way to do it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Even Tradablebits platform is an option. They give a good functionality and make it simpler to work with Facebook. http://apps.tradablebits.com/ I analyzed this platform for one of my apps.